# Recoger los datos de más de una consulta hecha al mismo tiempo

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un procedimiento en mysql que recorre un cursor mediante while, por cada iteración realiza una consulta nueva, así que al final del procedimiento tengo fácilmente más de una consulta.

Me gustaría saber si la librería `mysql` en php es capaz de reconocer cada uno de los resultados de las múltiples consultas y si es así por favor brindar un ejemplo o ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara, faltan detalles que ayuden a entender el contexto. Por ejemplo: ¿por qué lanzas varias consultas? ¿es una consulta sobre una sola tabla o basada en criterios que ya conoces de antemano?. Si quieres resolver el problema a nivel de base de datos, puedes lanzar una sola consulta que traiga los diferentes datos si el contexto lo permite. O puedes resolverlo en PHP, lanzando una por una las consultas, leyendo los resultados y guardándolos en una variable.

Comment: Ok, tengo una tabla padre y una de sus hijos. 

Realizo primero la consulta a la tabla padre y en base de esa consulta traigo a todos los hijos. Por cuestiones de contexto y comodidad esta me ha parecido una solución muy óptima, contemplé hacer una sola consulta pero resulta más difícil de esa forma (Obviando que el ejemplo de la tabla padres y la de hijos son ejemplos superficiales)

Tampoco puedo lanzar las consultas una por una porque como bien aclaré, vienen de un SP.

Comment: Me permito decirte que estás optando por una solución no óptima. Las bases de datos existen para poner en relación grandes o pequeñas cantidades de datos tomados de muchísimas o de pocas tablas. Haciendo consultas por separado renuncias a una de las principales ventajas de las bases de datos y tu código no será más rápido ni más sencillo. Lo correcto sería hacer una `JOIN` de la tabla padre y la tabla hijo y traer los datos juntos en una sola consulta. Eso sí, debes cuidar tus índices, tus relaciones entre tablas etc, para que las cosas no vayan lentas.